# FStream - Reading Integers inside file C++

Tags: c++

The objective is to read each integer in the following file and add them all up. But it seems I cannot cast the string line to an int for some reason. 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string line;
ifstream file ("Random.txt");
int lines;
int amount = 0;
while(getline(file, line)){
    lines++;
    amount += static_cast<int>(line);
}

cout << amount; 
return 0;

}
```

Txt file:

```
2
3
4
6
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't cast a string like that to anything, really.

If you know that the file contains only integers, you can just read them directly:

```
int   number;
while (file >> number)
{
    ++lines;
    amount += number;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A cast isn't the right tool to do so, it works for compatible types only.

What you actually need is a conversion function:

```
amount += std::stoi(line);
```

See the [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) please.

Comment: Thanks yet I am getting this error: [Error] 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @TylerEsposito Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: @TylerEsposito C++11 language standard?